# repeated measures anova: length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, anova, r-car

I conducted the repeated measures anova, that's my code, it's simple operation and i always did it quickly.

[Link to mydata in .csv format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sapkrwmbuh8g83/vivo1.csv?dl=0)

```
library(car)
vivo4  <- read.csv("vivo1.csv",sep=";",dec=",")

ageLevels  <- c(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12)
ageFactor  <- as.factor(ageLevels)
ageFrame  <- data.frame(ageFactor)

measures  <- function(data = vivo4, n = 4) { #n=4 is 4 variables
  ## Editor comment:
  ## correct way to initialize a list, don't use "list(n)"
  ## you can compare what you get from "list(4)" and "vector ("list", length = 4)"
  ## lmo's comment: don't use "list" for your variable name (may mask R function "list")
  ## I have corrected it as "Mylist"
  Mylist  <- vector("list", length = n)
  for(i in 0:3) {Mylist[[i+1]]  <- as.matrix(cbind(data[, 12*i + 1:12])) # 12 visits
  }
  Mylist
}

measures_list  <- measures()

models  <- lapply(
  measures_list, function(x) {
    ageModel  <- lm(x ~ 1)
    Anova.mlm (ageModel, idata = ageFrame, idesign = ~ageFactor)
  } )

models #View the result
```

but i got the error

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = colnames(B)) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

I have read many answers and can't understand whats wrong, i need supervision.

Comment: At a minimum it is poor form to name your objects the same as important object classes. I would recommend you use a name that is different than list, say myList.

Answer (score 1):

You have 12 levels in your dataset,but in agelevels, you indicated only 11 levels.
i.e.  you forgot indicate 14

ageLevels  <- c(1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,***14***)